# как сделать чтоб пользователи сами добавляли отзывы через бот

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot

```py
STATUS_TOP = (
('0', '☁️➖➖➖➖'),
('1', '➖➖➖➖'),
('2', '➖➖⛅️➖➖'),
('3', '➖➖➖➖'),
('4 ', '➖➖➖➖☀️'),
)
class Reviews(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Аккаунт')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1500, verbose_name='Отзыв', null=True, blank=True,  help_text="<xmp><b></b> <i></i> <del></del> <u></u> <code></code> <a href='https://postimages.org'>фото</a></xmp>")
    is_public = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Опубликован', default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Дата добавления отзыва')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_TOP, verbose_name='Рейтенг')
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Фото', upload_to='uploads/', null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    search_fields = ('request_number', 'user__username')
    product_category = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='Категория', to='Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Отзывы'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Отзывы'
        ordering = ['-date']
```

```py
import pytz
@dp.message_handler(text=['комментарии'])
async def send_buy(message: types.Message):
    reviews_list = Reviews.objects.filter(is_public=True).all()[:10]
    reviews = []

    for feedback in reviews_list:
        if feedback.user.tg_user_username:
            reviews.append(f'<code>{str(feedback.user.tg_user_first_name)}</code> \n Я оценил как: \n{feedback.get_status_display()} \n <b>{feedback.text}</b> \n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\n')
        else:
            reviews.append(f'️ <code>{str(feedback.user.tg_user_id)}</code> \n Я оценил как: \n{feedback.get_status_display()} \n <b>{feedback.text}</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\n')

    if reviews:
        aa = '\n\n'.join(reviews)
        await message.answer(f'<code></code><b>ВАШИ ОТЗЫВЫ</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\n\n\n\n{aa}', parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True)
    else:
        await message.answer(f'Ты ещё не оставлял отзывы!')
```

Comment: Поясните, какой бот? Какие отзывы? Нужно больше контекста

Comment: А перефразирую как добавлять данные в модели через Telegram пользователям

Comment: Ну, как и в любой другой ситуации. Получили от пользователя данные, сложили в базу?

Comment: а как это реализовать и вопрос возможно чтоб фотографии  опубликовывалось и отражалось в панели админа